# Force inner query to execute before outer query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have two tables that I need to join on:

Table VarValues has field Value that is a varchar and contains custom properties that can be text og int by the property type

Table Vars has the property type.

Table items has items in it, specifically an id and data that is fulltext indexed and I need to search.

When I query like this:

```
SELECT 
    distinct SelectedItems.itemid,SelectedItems.fileid
FROM 
    (
        SELECT  [values].itemid, convert(int, [value]) as fileid
        FROM 
            VarValues [values]
            JOIN Vars vars ON [values].VarID = vars. ID
        WHERE
            [type] = 6 --This type is an int
            AND
            [values].[value] <> ''
    ) as SelectedItems
    JOIN containstable(items, *, '<some query>') as items ON SelectedItems.fileid = items.[KEY]
```

The inner query only returns integers as the fileid but when the whole query is run I get an error because the first row in VarValues contains text although the type is not 6.

Is the query optimizer messing with my inner query? How can I make it stop? Or am I doing this completely wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optimizer can expand the views (including inline ones) and is free to decide the filter order.

In other words, it may first perform the join with the fulltext table and later filter the results on `type = 6` (which it seems to be doing in your case).

You may try adding `OPTION (FORCE ORDER)` to your query, however, it only guarantees the order of the tables in the join operations, not the order the filters are applied.

Try rewriting your query like this:

```
SELECT 
    distinct SelectedItems.itemid,SelectedItems.fileid
FROM 
    (
        SELECT  [values].itemid, CAST(CASE WHEN IsNumeric([value]) = 1 THEN [value] END AS INT) AS field
        FROM 
            VarValues [values]
            JOIN Vars vars ON [values].VarID = vars. ID
        WHERE
            [type] = 6 --This type is an int
            AND
            [values].[value] <> ''
    ) as SelectedItems
    JOIN containstable(items, *, '<some query>') as items ON SelectedItems.fileid = items.[KEY]
```

Comment: This did the trick. I see that I could move the filter on type to the select, but this way is more robust. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to save result of inner query in temporary/variable table and use it in main query.

Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE #vars (itemid, fileid)

-- store values for inner query
INSERT INTO 
    #vars (itemid, fileid)
SELECT  
    [values].itemid, 
    CAST(CASE WHEN IsNumeric([value] = 1 THEN [value] END AS INT) AS field
FROM 
    VarValues [values]
    JOIN 
        Vars vars 
    ON 
        [values].VarID = vars.ID
WHERE
    [type] = 6 --This type is an int
    AND [values].[value] <> ''


SELECT 
    distinct SelectedItems.itemid,SelectedItems.fileid
FROM 
    #vars as SelectedItems
    JOIN containstable(items, *, '<some query>') as items ON SelectedItems.fileid = items.[KEY]
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: This would perhaps give me the desired outcome but with way to much extra work. Adding the filter to the right spot was what was missing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could also add the condition `IsNumeric([value]) = 1` to the first join:

```
SELECT 
    distinct SelectedItems.itemid,SelectedItems.fileid
FROM 
    (
        SELECT  [values].itemid, convert(int, [value]) as fileid
        FROM 
            VarValues [values]
            JOIN Vars vars ON [values].VarID = vars. ID
                          AND IsNumeric([value]) = 1 
        WHERE
            [type] = 6 --This type is an int
            AND [values].[value] <> ''
    ) as SelectedItems
    JOIN containstable(items, *, '<some query>') as items
      ON SelectedItems.fileid = items.[KEY]
```

Comment: This is not guaranteed to be evaluated before the join.

Comment: This does give me the same results and looks more intuitive. Quassnoi, under what circumstances would this not be evaluated before the join?

Comment: @olafursverrir: Yes, @Quassnoi: is correct, it depends on the execution plan.

Comment: @olafursverrir: when the optimizer decides that it is more efficient to postpone the evaluation (in other words, at any moment).